# Want change default price like quantity in group products

Tags: magento2, grouped-products

I want to change the default price of of child product in group product like we make change in quantity.

We can change the price and save it but it will only change for that groupd product

Comment: Can you elaborate your question? You want to change the price from group product view? As simple thing, if you want to change the price for simple product in the group product view, then simple thing is that you can change price of simple product, it will reflect in group products also.

Comment: I dont want to change simple product price only want to change associated product price for only that group product like we do with defauly quantity.